# QuickSort method using only a single vector as input parameter in C++

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am attempting to write a QuickSort method in C++. I think my issue is with:

```
if( i <= j )
```

Because this is not comparing the values in the vector but my index. I attempted to use the brackets operator [] to access the value but then the code consumes memory and doesn't end on its own.

Also i would prefer to keep it a single method instead of splitting it into a method to partition and a method to sort.

STD::sort is implemented elsewhere along with other sort methods. I am just having trouble writing this one; and my input is restricted to a vector.

This is what i have

```
vector<double> QuickSort(vector<double> & vec1){

    double i = 0;
    double j = vec1.size()-1;
    int size = vec1.size();
    double tmp;

    double pivot = vec1[(i + j) / 2];

//   partition 

    while (i <= j) {
        while (vec1[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (vec1[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (vec1[j] <= vec1[j-1]) {
            tmp = vec1[j-1];
            vec1[j-1] = vec1[j];
            vec1[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

//    recursion 

    if (vec1[i] > vec1[i+1]) {
        QuickSort(vec1);
    }

    if (vec1[j] <vec1[j-1]) {
        QuickSort(vec1);
    }

    return vec1;
}
```

Suggestions and advice please.

Comment: You need to pass i and j as parameters to Quicksort.

Comment: ive seen a number of implementations that utilize three inputs. I am attempting to reduce that to one... a vector.

Comment: would not splitting it up to multiple functions resolve your problem ? just call the qsort with one parameter and internally call other implementation functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *first rule* of writing a recursive function is to define the case where there is nothing left to do. Your code does not do this, and **assumes** it is never reached. A vector with a size <= 1 is vacuously sorted, and testing `vec1[i] > vec1[i+1]` on such a vector is undefined behaviour.

The *second rule* of writing a recursive function is to make sure that you are reducing your problem size with each inner invocation. Your code does not do this, it passes the whole vector to itself (*twice*, if the first would ever return).

Vectors are not indexed by `double`s, but by `size_t`s (or `int`s with a sign conversion).

You are accepting `vec1` by reference, mutating it, then copying it in the return. Do *one* of those, not both.

Implementation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627/2610810)

```
namespace detail {    
    template<class FwdIt, class Compare = std::less<>>
    void QuickSortImpl(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Compare cmp = Compare{})
    {
        auto const N = std::distance(first, last);
        if (N <= 1) return;
        auto const pivot = *std::next(first, N / 2);
        auto const middle1 = std::partition(first, last, [=](auto const& elem){ 
            return cmp(elem, pivot); 
        });
        auto const middle2 = std::partition(middle1, last, [=](auto const& elem){ 
            return !cmp(pivot, elem);
        });
        QuickSortImpl(first, middle1, cmp);
        QuickSortImpl(middle2, last, cmp);
    }   
}

void QuickSort(vector<double>& vec1)
{
    detail::QuickSortImpl(vec1.begin(), vec1.end());
}
```

If you really *insist* on having one function parameter, it can be done with a range library ([`boost::range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) or [`range v3`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3))

```
template<class Range>
void QuickSort(Range& range)
{
    auto const N = std::distance(range.begin(), range.end());
    if (N <= 1) return;
    auto const pivot = *std::next(range.begin(), N / 2);
    auto left_range = boost::partition<boost::return_begin_found>(
        range.begin(), 
        range.end(), 
        [=](auto const& elem){ 
            return elem < pivot; 
        }
    );
    auto right_range = boost::partition<boost::return_found_end>(
        left_range.end(), 
        range.end(), 
        [=](auto const& elem){ 
            return !(pivot < elem);
        }
    );
    QuickSort(left_range);
    QuickSort(right_range);
}
```

Comment: First off, thank you. Second, holy crap. I will seek to attain your knowledge base and skills. cuz wow. thats some elegant code.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code like this. I decided pivot index as last item. and added some test code. it worked normally. I think that if QuickSort function has from, to index parameters, can be implemented more simply.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std ;

void printvector(vector<double> v) {
cout << "vector : " ;
for (double n : v) {
cout << n << " " ;
}
cout << endl ;
}

vector<double> QuickSort(vector<double>& vec1){

    double i = 0;
    double j = vec1.size()-2;
    double tmp;
    int pivotindex = vec1.size()-1 ;
    double pivot = vec1[pivotindex];

    if ( vec1.size()<=1 )
        return vec1 ;

    cout << "QuickSort: ";
    printvector(vec1) ;

    while (i <= j) {
        while (vec1[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (vec1[j] > pivot)
            j--;
         if (i <= j) {
            tmp = vec1[i];
            vec1[i] = vec1[j];
            vec1[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    // pivot change
    vec1[pivotindex] = vec1[i] ;
    vec1[i]=pivot ;
    pivotindex=i ;

    cout << "pivotting: ";
    printvector(vec1) ;

    if (vec1.size()<=2 )
        return vec1 ;
    // partition
    vector<double> left_vec, right_vec ;
    vector<double>::iterator pivotiter = vec1.begin()+pivotindex ;
    copy(vec1.begin(), pivotiter, back_inserter(left_vec)) ;
    copy(pivotiter+1, vec1.end(), back_inserter(right_vec)) ;

    cout << "left: ";
    printvector(left_vec) ;
    cout << "right: ";
    printvector(right_vec) ;

   if (left_vec.size()>0 ) {
        QuickSort(left_vec);
        copy(left_vec.begin(), left_vec.end(), vec1.begin()) ;
    }
   if (right_vec.size()>0 ) {
        QuickSort(right_vec);
        copy(right_vec.begin(), right_vec.end(), pivotiter+1) ;
    }
    return vec1;
}

int main()
{
//vector<double> v { 5 } ;
//vector<double> v { 5, 3 } ;
//vector<double> v { 5, 3, 1 } ;
//vector<double> v { 1, 3, 5 } ;
//vector<double> v { 9,4,8,5,1,2,7 } ;
vector<double> v  ;
//srand( time(NULL) ) ;
int64_t now = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
srand( now ) ;
for (int i=0; i<rand()%30+1; i++) {
    v.push_back( rand()%10000 ) ;
}

cout << "input values: " ;
printvector(v) ;

vector<double> ret = QuickSort(v) ;
cout << "output values: " ;
printvector(ret) ;
cout << endl << endl ;

return 0 ;
}
```

output is this.

```
input values: vector : 1778 9400 9330 783 3148 2029 9685 
QuickSort: vector : 1778 9400 9330 783 3148 2029 9685 
pivotting: vector : 1778 9400 9330 783 3148 2029 9685 
left: vector : 1778 9400 9330 783 3148 2029 
right: vector : 
QuickSort: vector : 1778 9400 9330 783 3148 2029 
pivotting: vector : 1778 783 2029 9400 3148 9330 
left: vector : 1778 783 
right: vector : 9400 3148 9330 
QuickSort: vector : 1778 783 
pivotting: vector : 783 1778 
QuickSort: vector : 9400 3148 9330 
pivotting: vector : 3148 9330 9400 
left: vector : 3148 
right: vector : 9400 
output values: vector : 783 1778 2029 3148 9330 9400 9685
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `std::sort` unless you have a very good reason not to do so.

In order to have a function taking only one parameter, a wrapper of `std::sort` may look like this, but you are copying your vector. If you do not like this you can pass it by reference.

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <algorithm>  // std::sort
#include <vector>     // std::vector

std::vector<double> mySort(const std::vector<double> unsorted) {
    std::vector<double> sorted = unsorted; 
    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end()); 
    return sorted;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> myvector{32, 71, 12, 45, 26, 80, 53, 33};

    for (const auto item : myvector) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto myvector_sorted = mySort(myvector);

    for (const auto item : myvector_sorted) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Nevertheless, the bottom of your implementation is not meaningful, since

```
if (vec1[i] > vec1[i + 1]) {
    QuickSort(vec1);
}
if (vec1[j] < vec1[j - 1]) {
    QuickSort(vec1);
}
```

will always start `QuickSort` with `vec1`. You need to pass `i` and `j` as well. In order to have one parameter interface you can write

```
vector<double> QuickSort(vector<double> & vec1, int i = 0, int j = vec1.size() - 1 ) {
    int size = vec1.size();
    ....
```

Comment: I am using sort in another section of the project to show its complexity(big O) in comparison. I Have implemented a bubblesort, insertsort, and a selection sort that all work properly, i am just having issues getting this one working.